# See vertex count of subdivided object before applying modifier

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, polycount

There are answers about the info bar (by default at the bottom right of Blender 2.8) but it seems it only shows current stats on the selected object (when in edit mode) and not what the stats will be after a modifier like Subdivision is applied.

Comment: You have to be in Object Mode to get the final vertex count of that object. Edit Mode always shows the base mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.80 python console code examples of three possible methods to do this. Some of these methods differ slightly in 2.7x, consult the documentation.

For  the simplest of examples Have the default cube with default subsurf modifier. The "modified" cube has 24 faces.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> len(C.object.data.polygons)
6
```

**Bmesh `from_object`**

Creating a bmesh from the object, produces a bmesh with the modifiers applied.  *This would be my preferred method*

```
>>> import bmesh
>>> bm = bmesh.new()
>>> bm.from_object(C.object, C.depsgraph)
>>> len(bm.faces)
24
```

Very similarly `Object.to_mesh(...)` returns a modified mesh. *remove from the data collection when done calculating stats*.

```
>>> me = C.object.to_mesh(C.depsgraph, True)
>>> len(me.polygons)
24
```

The `Scene.statistics(...)` method returns the statistics string seen on header.  Grep the required data from the string, create a linked dupe, re-run stats remove the dupe object.

```
>>> C.scene.statistics(C.view_layer)
'Scene Collection | Cube | Verts:26 | Faces:24 | Tris:48 | Objects:0/3 | Mem: 11.6 MB | v2.80.48'

>>> bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=True)
{'FINISHED'}


>>> C.scene.statistics(C.view_layer)
'Scene Collection | Cube.001 | Verts:52 | Faces:48 | Tris:96 | Objects:1/4 | Mem: 15.3 MB | v2.80.48'

>>>
```

Comment: Right, I see. The time these take is similar to just copying the mesh, applying the modifier and checking the vertex count there, for me at least.

Thank you for your answers, I hope this will be a feature on the interface one day.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to be in object mode to have the vertex count of the object including its modifiers.

To have the polycount of a selected object, for now, there is no dedicated statistics for that. A workaround would be to temporary isolate your object in a layer (or collection in 2.80) and hide the others. Then you will have the right stats.